# Hibernate replicated Ehcache

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I have an app built with JSF Spring JPA2.1 Hibernate 5.1 and ehcache 2.10.
I need to create a replicated cache as I want to create a glassfish4.1 cluster with two nodes, and the both nodes to stay in sync in which is related to 2nd level cache, especially acl cache used by spring security.
This is how my persistence.xml file looks like :

```
<persistence-unit name="CCPU" transaction-type="JTA"> 
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>         
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/contactCenter</jta-data-source>       
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>

        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />

        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path" value="ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>           
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.session.events.log" value="false"/>

    </properties>       
</persistence-unit>
```

and this is how my ehcache file looks like:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" 
     updateCheck="false" 
     monitoring="autodetect" 
     maxBytesLocalHeap="2048M"
     >              
 <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory 
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" 
properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1, multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=32"/>

<!-- Configure a cache manager peer listener that listens for messages from peers -->
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=localhost, port=40001,socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>


<!-- elemets expire in one our -->
<defaultCache
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="1800"
        timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        statistics="true"        
   >

    <!-- Configure a cache event listener to actually replicate changes to the other cache instances -->
    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true "/>
   </defaultCache>


   <cache name="aclCache"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600"
        timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        statistics="true"
        >
        <!-- Configure a cache event listener to actually replicate changes to the other cache instances -->
    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true, replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true "/>
    </cache>
```

The problem is that when I start the app I git this exception while biulding the Hibernate SessionFactory:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.distribution.CacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:426)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:270)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1116)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:892)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:873)
at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.start(SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory.java:65)
... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.distribution.CacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCachePeerListeners(ConfigurationHelper.java:163)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:786)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:471)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:395)
... 76 more
```

P.S - I use Glassfish 4.1.1. I tried to debug a little bit the issue and it seems that the exception is thrown somewhere in the WebApplicationClassLoader. The class is loaded initially by the EhCacheDefaultClassLoader...

Comment: anyone, any idea ?

Comment: updated answer with more info.